# how to show view from root controller ios app

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, didselectrowatindexpath

I am very new to ios development so pardon me if I am asking a naive question.
My app is tab bar application, so root controller is tab bar controller with 2 tab items.
my first tab item links to a navigation controller which in turn has first view controller as table view controller
now when i tap a cell in this table view controller i want to show one of the tab bar controllers (say item 2).

I assume I can use delgate didSelectRowAtIndexPath but how to get access to these nested views and show it?

any suggestions.

Comment: If the rootviewcontroller is the UITabBarController, you probably can just access it and use setSelectedIndex to switch.  Look at the docs for UITabBarController....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tab bar controllers allow you to keep each tabs view controller hierarchy independent.  Because of this you'll have to come up with a creative way to share data between view controller hierarchies using core data, singletons, user defaults, notifications, or other methods that could be otherwise be  simplified.  There is probably a better way to design your application.

That being said, to accomplish what you want all you have to do is add:

```
navigationController?.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
```

Inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in order to show the second tab.